# How to get data value of one input field from a list?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I get the value of the first input field from a list?

```
<button id="hello">get data</button><br><br>
   <table> <td><label for="voucher_<?php echo $counter; ?>">D/N Number <?php echo $counter; ?></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="voucher_<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="input-field exsmall-input" value="<?php echo $voucher; ?>" placeholder="D/N Number" id="voucher_<?php echo $counter; ?>" required>
    </td></table>
```

When I run the above code the number of rows varies depending on the counter.If I want to get the value of the first DN number ,what shall I do ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hello').click(function(){
          var name = $("#voucher").val();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

When I run this javascript I get undefined vales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hello').click(function(){
          var name = $("div[id^='voucher']:visible:first").val();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Or:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hello').click(function(){
          var name = $("input[type=text]:visible:first").val();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because you have used wrong selector to target input element. input element do not have id voucher. You need to put the ID to make existing code work.

Or, You can use attribute starts with selector here from current HTML:

```
 $('#hello').click(function(){
      var name = $("input[name^='voucher_']").val();
      alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hello').click(function() {
        var name = $('table').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first')
            .val();

    });
});
```